# redirect to page using java script according to checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

i don't know why it's n't work  , want according to check box value redirect to page or do nothing . and this is the code

```
<html>
<body>

<form onsubmit= "lol()" >
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function lol()
{
if(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true)
{
window.location="http://www.google.com";
}
else
{
// want do nothing and stay at same page .
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

how can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you need to here if you want to keep the form not doing anything in false condition.

1. When you call the function you need to use return. So that the form won't submit until it got the return true value.
2. In your function else part you need to mentioned return=false. It will stop the form submitting.

**Javascript:**

```
    function lol()
    {    
     if(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true)
     {    
        window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
     }
     else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
  <form onsubmit="return lol()">
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbes9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in jquery

```
$('#myCheck').click(function() {
    if($('#myCheck').is(':checked')){
        window.location = 'http://www.naveedramzan.com';
    }
});
```

Comment: Isnt jQuery an extension of javascript?

Comment: Ah ok. 

For using jquery, you need to include jquery file.

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function:

```
function lol()
{
if(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true)
{
window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
}
else
{
// want do nothing and stay at same page .
}
}
```

To redirect from one page to another, you use `window.location.href`, not `window.location`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `location.assign()` function

```
function lol()
{
if(document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true)
{
window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
}
else
{
// want do nothing and stay at same page .
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a post for this, everything can be handled client side:

```
<body>
    Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="lol()">

    <script>
        function lol() {
            if (document.getElementById("myCheck").checked === true) {
                window.location = "http://www.google.com";
            }
            else {
                // want do nothing and stay at same page .
                alert("staying on page");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```